Why are my WordPress website's pages getting redirected to the main page?
I am creating a WordPress website on the topic of computers. Now, the sub-pages are getting redirected to the main page. The slugs are in place. Below, is the URL of the website.
https://computerbasicshub.net/
https://computerbasicshub.net/index.php/webaccess/
The pages that are published are being redirected. How do I fix this problem and why is it happening? Also, where can I view the website's map?
Any assistance would be good.
I published the pages I wanted to put on the Internet at this point and created slugs for them.

This question may be better suited for wordpress.stackexchange.co.nz, but have you turned on pretty links, and what web server are you using?  (I wonder if you are missing the .htaccess or equivalent.   Also, is lightspeed set to process your .htaccess file, and does your .htaccess file include the appropriate rewrite rules for Wordpress?

I'm not a techie in PHP, but shouldn't the link be https://computerbasicshub.net/webaccess/index.php/?  If I read this the way it's written, it would appear the webaccess path is inside of the php file, or is this another way to pass some variable?

@Trebor The URL is weird, but not neccessarily wrong.  The slug "webaccess" would go at the end of the URL.   In the typical Wordpress install  [ controlled by the webserver, outside Wordpress eg through the use of .htaccess ] the default page (index.php) is called and the slug becomes a parameter.   Of-course, having index.php in the URL is unusual - but I poked around the site a bit and I don't think thats the issue.

@davidgo thanks.  I used WP regularly, but have never seen that URL format before.  I learned something new.  Thanks.

Pages on your WordPress site may be redirecting to the main page due to several reasons, such as plugin conflicts, incorrect permalink settings, or issues with your .htaccess file. It’s also possible that a theme or security plugin is enforcing redirection. Check your settings, disable any recent plugins, and review your error logs for clues.

Pages redirecting to the main page could be due to plugin conflicts, permalink issues, or problems with your .htaccess file. Check your settings, disable recent plugins, and review error logs for more information.

Try simply re-saving the permalinks settings in dashboard > settings > permalinks

-1?  This often works as a fix when pretty links don't work.  I owned a web hosting business and found it to be a solution when everything else looked right.
